# What's the proper way to write HTML to a WebBrowser in C#?

Tags: c#, html, browser

If instead of navigating to a webpage in a WebBrowser, you want to set the HTML property directly, what's the proper way to do it?

Is it like this?

```
myWebBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
myWebBrowser.Document.Write("<html><body>Test</body></html>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this (instead of the *about:blank*  *document.write* combo):

```
myWebBrowser.DocumentText = sourceCode;
```

seems to solve various issues such as running the following JavaScript when IE7 is installed on the system:

```
window.location = "#test";
```

If IE 7 is installed, this will cause an **Error: Invalid argument** message to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [WebBrowser.DocumentStream Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) to write the data you need.